# Android sending post to rest service request with Empty MultiValueMap

Tags: java, android, jersey, resttemplate

I am trying to send a MultiValueMap in a POST request, I have been trying many ways and I am always receiving the MultiValueMap as null in the server, I have another client using AngularJS and I can send the params well, this is my client code in Android:

```
HttpEntity<Object> objectHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(map);
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
                restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, objectHttpEntity, String.class);
```

Tha it is filled in this way:

```
org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();


    map.add("name", "daniel");
map.add("lastName", "hernandez");
map.add("message", "dummy");
map.add("email", "mail@some.com");
map.add("phone", "4545645465");
```

I am reaching the server, but it is reading the values in the map with null values.

This is my rest:

```
@POST
    @Path("/message/create")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(@Context UriInfo uri) {

        try {
            javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap<String, String> parameters = uri.getQueryParameters();

.....
```

This is working well in angularjs

```
var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://someip:port/wsapp1-1.0/service/contactMessage/message/create',
            params: {
                name: scope.contactus.name,
                lastName: scope.contactus.lastName,
                message: scope.contactus.message,
                email: scope.contactus.email,
                phone: scope.contactus.phone
            }
        };
```

Comment: There are no query parameters with a post request i think. That's for a get.

Comment: I am using the same service but with a angularjs client

Comment: Yes? And? I was talking about get and post. You should do the same. And how would i know what that angular client is doing?

Comment: So change HttpMethod.POST to HttpMethod.GET to see if there is someting in what i said.

Comment: I am not receiving any GET request in my service, it wouldn't work as magic, there are no GET method servers to get that request

Comment: Well then still the problem could be that there are no query parameters during a post. That you should use getQueryParameters(); only if you expect a get. So not now. And why dont you tell if the angular client is getting or posting?

Comment: well, I made a mistake writting "queryparams" , just the params the MultivaluedMap I want to send, just that, I am receiving it that from Angularjs without tricks

Comment: I have updated the post with angular code

Comment: Never saw such Android code. What is restTemplate? And .exchange() would do the connection and post? There is nothing to see.

Comment: We cannot see what you send with  map.add("lastName", form.getApellido().getText().toString());. If you had written  map.add("lastName", "Daniel"); we would. And what is form?

Comment: Well , I will update the case, with literal string, and the instance of resttemplate , I am looking to send the Map to the service.

Comment: You have a `jersey` tag but did not mention it. And i never saw that resttemplate before. You could tell about it i think. And where is the `send` call?

Comment: I'm not aware spring REST services, my hunch: just try adding ( HttpEntity<MultivaluedMap<String, String>> requestEntity )as a resource method parameter. Doing requestEntity.getBody() should give you the multivalued map sent in the request.